# Autocomplete or suggest in Excel

Tags: excel

I inserted a list next to a cell, so that it can use the 'autocomplete' or 'suggest'; however, it pulls words from above, instead of the list beginning adjacent to that cell, going down about a few hundred cells. I found a video that shows what I'm trying to do.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PVEzHbdHf1Y

Does anyone know why it isn't suggesting words from a list to the left of the cell, and instead is suggesting words from a few cells above?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PVEzHbdHf1Y

Comment: Welcome to SO. Without knowing what your code is, we have no idea how to help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm trying to fix this, without code. It should autocomplete bc the cell is 'linked' to the list, but its pulling from another (possibly linked) cell above. I deleted and moved it so it wouldnt be linked to the other cells, yet it suggest those words.

Comment: The autocomplete values need to be in the SAME column! There must be a link!

Comment: I was using the list adjacent as the link? It worked in that YouTube video. Not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

It's necessary that the autocomplete values are in the SAME column as the field where autocomplete shall work! If there are blank fields between the new, empty field and the autocomplete values there needs to be a link (e.g. with "x" values in a neighbour column:

```
   A         B
1 A(lpha)    x
2            x
3            x
4            x
5            x
6  Alpha     x
7  Bravo
8  Charly
```

Typing an "A" in A1 will be autocompleted to Alpha if a "link" to the autocomplete values exist (The "x" values in column B are "linking" the empty values of a to the other values!)